# Which artifact should I deploy to prod when using Git Flow?

Tags: git, deployment, release-management, gitflow

Suppose I have the following series of commits when using Git Flow

[image: git flow example]

We have said that no new features will be included in the next release and have created a release branch (D). QA has started testing and has found a bug, which we have fixed (E).

QA conclude their testing, so we call the release done and merge back to master and develop and tag the version on master (F).

Our CI release process observes the new tag created on master, builds the code and produces an artifact.

The problem is that while the code might be identical, the artifact that is produced at E and F is not guaranteed to be 100% binary identical. Some aspect of the build may not be able to reproduced in the same way. For example, if you rely on a package manager to supply dependencies over HTTP, you are at the mercy of an external system to act identically for both builds. You would hope that most of the time it would but there is no guarantee.

Which artifact should I deploy to prod?

If I deploy the artifact from E, isn't it a bit strange to have tagged the master branch as v1? I have to kind of *retrospectively* name a commit as being the release version.

If I deploy the artifact from F, there is a (small) danger that it's broken in a way which E was not. QA could re-test F, but then that's somewhat of a wasted cycle and what happens if they find a critical bug? We'd need a second release to fix it and v1.0.0 becomes unused and pointless.

Comment: Why would your compiler run with different optimization levels?

Comment: @ThomasOwens It was just an example. Maybe a bad one, since it is unlikely to change. More likely in our scenario, we rely upon a package manager and are pulling dependencies via HTTP. We are 100% at its mercy to provide the same artifact both times. If it doesn't - maybe some other team replaces a release version because they don't know what they're doing - then our build has changed for reasons outside of our control

Comment: If you're worried about external dependencies, then why haven't you set up your own repository that stores the specific version (and perhaps even built binaries) so you don't have to worry about a particular version changing or going away? My point is that there is that if your source (including config, which should probably be in source control) is identical, the resultant binaries should also be identical.

Comment: @ThomasOwens You seem to be missing my point. If you build an artifact twice, there is necessarily the possibility of some difference emerging. I can take all the precautions I like to make the second build more likely to resemble the first - setting up our own repository (which we have) - but no amount of precautions will give me a *guarantee*. It seems to me that the only way to get that guarantee is to not build the thing twice. What's even the necessity of the 2nd build, anyway? It's existence is just a side effect of my VCS workflow.

Comment: @ThomasOwens "*the resultant binaries **should** also be identical*" This reinforces my point actually. Note that you didn't use the word 'will'.

Comment: If your environment does not guarantee that the binaries will be identical to the extent necessary, then there's something wrong with your environment. This is something that you need to account for during tool qualifications. If you're building a life critical system, you have different constraints than something that can't cause harm, injury, or death. Given an input, your toolchain needs to be able to produce equivalent outputs, depending on what you consider to be equivalent. That could be binary equivalence or just functional equivalence.

Comment: Does your software present a version number in any way (UI, package manager, etc.)? If so, which version numbers should be used for commits D, E and F?

Comment: @ThomasOwens That sounds like an answer to me

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau We do bake in some meta-data gathered at build time (commit hash, build time, build host etc.) which is accessible via an admin console, but I'd also be interested to hear your thoughts if this weren't true.

Comment: This is exactly the problem with Git Flow imo - you can either do away with release branches and ship master, or do away with master and ship your release branches, but deploying an entirely separate build to production than was deployed to your test environments is just a plain old bad idea.

Comment: If your build process is not determinate, that is a flaw of the build process regardless of whether you use GitFlow or not.

Comment: You can and maybe should compare binaries -- among other things, this is an approach used to verify that (1) the source code being archived (in master) is the source that was tested, that (2) dependencies such as compilers, tools and third party libraries are the same as tested and (3) that full clean builds are the same as incremental builds.

Comment: @ErikEidt The release branch version was tested and approved. Suppose I build the master one and the binary is different, then what?

Comment: @Michael Then you know for sure that you have a problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the artefacts you build don't contain any information that is tied to the presence/absence of a tag during build time, then there is a way out without rebuilding the artefacts.

If you arrange your environment such that the master branch only accepts fast-forward merges, then it can be guaranteed that "commit F" and "commit E" are actually one and the same commit (same commit hash). In that case, the tag would actually be placed on "commit E" and the exact same artefacts that QA approved can be released as being version 1.0.0.

This works, because in a fast-forward commit, no new commit is created but only marker for the head of the target branch is moved. Fast forward merges are only possible if there are no commits on master that are not also present on the release branch.

Comment: I’ve downvoted because a key premise of GitFlow as originally proposed was to never fast forward.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is that while the code might be identical, the artifact that is produced at E and F is not guaranteed to be 100% binary identical. Some aspect of the build may not be able to reproduced in the same way.

**This is not a GitFlow problem, it's a problem with your build process.**

If your build process does not produce the same result with the same source code, then that is a useless process. Your build process needs to be determinate. GitFlow is about managing source code, not about making your builds determinate. *Your builds need to be determinate regardless of what source control strategy you use.*

To address your example:

> For example, if you rely on a package manager to supply dependencies over HTTP, you are at the mercy of an external system to act identically for both builds. You would hope that most of the time it would but there is no guarantee.

**You should never be dependent on a system you don't control for your release builds**

It's perfectly OK to use package managers as part of your development and build process. But, if you are going to create release builds that need to be exactly the same, then you should not be dependent on something that behaves in ways that will surprise you. You can eliminate the surprise from package managers by:

1. Pinning the versions of your dependencies. Any package manager worth using will let you do this. You should definitely be doing this already.
2. Caching the fetched dependent artifacts that the software you wish to release depends upon. That way, it doesn't matter what happens on the upstream system, you always have the correct dependent artifact when you need it. There are many solutions that provide this sort of capability depending on what kind of artifacts and what package manager you are using.

EDIT: Based on the comments, there's a lot of confusion about why a determinate  build process is desirable or even possible. Adding to this confusion is the additional trivial details of GitFlow itself, which are actually completely unimportant to addressing the *actual* problem in the question, that being that it is not known what the resulting binary from the build process actually is.

**You need a determinate build process**

The reason why you need a build process that produces the same result from the same source code, is to eliminate an entire class of errors or deliberate security vulnerabilities that can be introduced during the build process. If you know with certainty that the process always produces the same binaries from the same source code, then you and other parties who build the software (e.g. other developers on the team and your QA department, or in open source world, other developers on the Internet) can determine if the build itself is "correct" and know that any deviations require scrutiny because they likely signify larger problems.

More relevant to the example posed in the question, if we take the assumption that commit E and commit F contain identical source code, then it does not matter if the build is produced from commit E or commit F, because the result of the process should be identical. The input to the process is identical, so the output from the process should be identical. If it is not, then you have a very big problem, because if the build of commit E and the build of commit F are not the same, then multiple builds of commit E and commit F across time will not be the same either.

That state of affairs is bad because the *entire point* of having a revision control system is to ensure that the state of the resulting software as it existed during a specific instance in history is preserved. The *entire point* of having a build system is to make sure the software builds in a consistent, error free way. If this isn't how things work in practice, then you are doing a lot of extra work to gain none of the benefits of stability that these tools are supposed to give you.

**"Okay, so which commit should I release?"**

It doesn't matter which commit you release if they *actually are* the same source code. Obviously, you should only release a build that has been tested. You should always release builds to customers that you have tested. But whether it is commit E and commit F doesn't matter. Your compiler doesn't even know what a commit is. **Focusing on which commit is the *input* to the build process is missing the actual problems you have from not knowing what the *output* of the build process is.**

**"But reproducible builds are impossible"**

Many major software companies, security professionals, and the Debian project would disagree with you rather strongly about that. You can read more about how to make reproducible builds here: https://reproducible-builds.org/

**"Why would I ever want to build the same code twice?"**

There are lots of reasons why you'd want to build the same code twice, here's a non-exhaustive list of reasons:

- Sometimes you need to replace a release build that the customer has lost and that the CI system no longer keeps a copy of.
- Other people may want to build the software themselves, e.g. other developers on your team, the open source community, or customers who paid for your source code. If the build is not reproducible, how will any of them know they did it right?
- Suppose your build system breaks or you need to recreate it on another machine. How will you validate that the new system is working correctly?
- Depending on the architecture of your application, your build process may include compiling a collection of modules independently which are then assembled to form the final artifact to deploy. You would certainly want the modules you did not change to build exactly the same regardless of how many commits ago the changes were made (even better, you'd cache these modules someplace to speed up the process if they are unchanged).
- Even better, if you know with certainty that a module does not change if the source code does not change, you can skip building those modules completely and speed up your build process.
- If your software is cross-platform, you may have builds for each platform from the same source code.

**"But the second build off of master in the way I understand GitFlow is totally pointless!"**

Nowhere here did I say you should do a second build off of master, or follow GitFlow however you understand it with robot-like devotion. The very first words in the answer are "This is not a GitFlow problem" exactly because the trivia of what commit gets built does not change the fact that **the same *input* to the build process should result in the same *output*.**

Comment: As a former git flower, I strongly disagree. The single most effective way of making releases predictable is to build and package once, test that package and deploy that same package. This has been a basic tenet of good deployment pipelines for over a decade. Idempotent build process or not, there's no good reason not to do this, and Git Flow in its purest form forces you not to and gives you little in return.

Comment: @AntP Nowhere do I advocate for "GitFlow in its purest form." If you don't test the exact same artefact you are releasing then you're doing testing wrong. My only assumption is the same one in the question, that commit E and commit F have _exactly the same code._

Comment: Or to state the point in alternative terms: the fixation on GitFlow is distracting the questioner from all of the important parts of the build and release process that must be deficient based upon the description of the concerns considered relevant.

Comment: @Joe, well I *am* using GitFlow, and that's specifically what the question is about. Given I am happy with this workflow and that "*if you don't test the exact same artefact you are releasing then you're doing testing wrong*", when do you suggest I build this artifact?

Comment: @Michael It doesn't matter if you're using GitFlow; Don't release any build you haven't tested. If the source code is actually the same for commit E and commit F, then it does not matter which one you test and ship as long as the one you pick is tested. Your problem is that if your build process cannot guarantee that E and F build the same when E and F have the same code, than it cannot guarantee that E or F built at any different time is the same either. Your problem is bigger than GitFlow.

Comment: @Joe "if your build process cannot guarantee" the problem is that I don't believe *any* build process can *guarantee* that

Comment: @Michael Really? Computers exhibit deterministic behavior on my planet when executing programs written in Turing complete languages. Is this not true on your planet?

Comment: @Joe If you build your software (artefact A) and then test it and then build it again (artefact B) and come to me and say "let's release artefact B," I'm going to tell you to release artefact A. If you tell me it was built from the same commit (although with Git Flow it won't have been due to no-FF) with the same compile flags, with the same configuration, with locked package versions, with all possible temporal couplings in the build accounted for, with the same colour mouse and on the same WiFi... I'm going to tell you to release artefact A. Why? Because there's no sane reason not to.

Comment: @AntP I don't know why you're harping on this because I haven't said anything to disagree with it.

Comment: @Joe we are "harping" because your standpoint does not make sense, or you doing a poor job of conveying it. If you believe the artifact at E is the one that should be deployed, why *even bother* to rebuild it again? Whether you think that a good build should be guaranteed to be 100% reproducible every time or not, if you're not deploying the artifact then that 2nd build off master is pointless.

Comment: @Michael I have expanded the answer substantially in order to address all comments by you and Ant P